# print keys from a file of dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a file. It looks like its composed of dictionaries.

I'm trying to print out the keys from the file.

```
import json
tweet = json.load


file = open( "CRP.txt",'r')
lines = file.readlines()
file.close()

print file.keys()

for line in lines:
    if line.find( "id" ):
        print tweet.keys("CRP.txt")
        print keys.id
```

When I run this, this pops up

```
AttributeError:'file' has no attribute 'key'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are already importing json, but using it in wrong way. Correct way will be to use it like:

```
import json

with open( "CRP.txt",'r') as json_file:  # Efficient way to open files
    data = json.load(json_file)  # Load the file object
    for key in data:   # Iterate over all the keys
        print key
```

If you also need the corresponding value, iterate like:

```
for key, value in data.items(): 
    print key, value
```

Comment: Thanks!! I have a question thought. Lets say the file contains multiple dictionaries. What would you have to do to print out all the keys of the dictionaries?

Comment: @user: That is entirely different question. You should ask it as a separate question

Answer (score -1):

`AttributeError:'file' has no attribute 'key'` error is for the line `print file.keys()` . open() returns a file object i.e., "file" in your case. This file object does not have keys() method.

You might want to look at this for more information on how to use keys() https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_keys.htm .